How to show that $\mathrm{Tor}_{2}^{\mathbb{Z}}=0$
Since $\mathrm{Tor}$ functor preserve direct limit and any
Abelian group is direct limit of its finitely generated subgroups, and by the fundamental theorem of f.g. abelian groups, it reduces to the case when $A ,B$ are cyclic groups, say $A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. The exact sequence
$$
0
\longrightarrow n\mathbb{Z}
\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} 
\longrightarrow A 
\longrightarrow 0
$$
induces exact sequence
$$
\longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}_2^{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},B) 
\longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}_2^{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B) 
\longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(n\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}},B) 
\longrightarrow
$$
Since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$ are flat, $\mathrm{Tor}_2^{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B)=0$.
Is that correct?

This works only for finitely generated abelian groups, don't you want the general result ?

@julio_es_sui_glace This is correct and works for arbitrary abelian groups, not sure why you'd think otherwise.

@BenSteffan The resolution by $n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z$ only handles cyclic groups. However the OP began with a comment about "wlog we may reduce to f.g. groups" so it's immaterial in any case.

@FShrike ...exactly. If you read the first sentence it should be clear why the reduction is justified.

@BenSteffan You are right, I was mislead by the terminology direct limit, which probably means colimit

@julio_es_sui_glace well now we have three valid solutions on the board so... none the worse off I guess :-)

Here is a more general proof (using the same exact mechanic but working on more complicated rings); the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ has a nice property: submodules of free modules are free (or subgroups of free abelian groups are free). It is given by the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is PID. This gives you a very nice exact sequence (so a nice projective resolution):
$$0 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0$$
where $P_0 = \bigoplus_{a \in A} \mathbb{Z}$ with the map that sends $(1,a)$ to $a$, and $P_1$ is the kernel of this map (which is thus a submodule of $P_0$, hence free).
You thus have (since free modules are flat) an exact sequence:
$$0 \to \operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_2 (A,B) \to 0 \to 0 \to \operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(A,B) \to P_0 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B \to P_0 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B \to P_0 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B \to 0 $$
Which means $\forall A,B$ $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_2 (A,B)=0$.

Some further information; as @FShrike suggested, this comes from the fact that $\mathrm{Mod}-\mathbb{Z}$ is an hereditary abelian category. The definition is $\mathcal{C}$ (abelian, exact, triangulated or extriangulated) is hereditary if $\mathrm{Ext}^{\geqslant 2}_\mathcal{C} = 0$, or equivalently if $\mathcal{C}$ has enough projective, every object $X$ has a projective resolution of length $\leq 1$. This is the case for $\mathrm{Mod}-R$ if $R$ is left or right hereditary which is the case when $R$ is PID.
If you have this, since every projective module is flat, you can have the same exact proof by taking a projective resolution of length $1$:  $0 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to X$.

It is worth noting that if the (potentially noncommutative) ring $R$ satisfies either left or right hereditariness (e.g. if $R$ is a Dedekind domain), then the same result holds that $\mathsf{Tor}^R_\ast$ vanishes in degree greater than one by the same proof. We don't need $P_1$ to be free, just projective.

@FShrike Yes but I don't think the OP knows about hereditary condition I can add some paragraph about it

Your proof works fine, but admittedly uses some rather big tools for a fact that can be proved using elementary means. Here's a slightly different spin on julio_es_sui_glace's answer using only the/a definition of $\newcommand{\Tor}{\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}}\Tor$: Let
$$
    0 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0
$$
be a free resolution of $A$. The groups $\Tor_k(A, B)$ are then the homology groups of the complex
$$
    \ldots \to 0 \to 0 \to P_1 \otimes B \to P_0 \otimes B \to 0
$$
from which it follows immediately that $\Tor_k(A, B) = 0$ for all $k \geq 2$.
